# timer application on android, threading

Tags: android, multithreading, service, timer

I have to write a simple stopper aplication on android.

The problem is that it should keep working even when application is in background (closed activity).

Where should I keep timer's thread ?

I was thinking about doing it in a service, but updating UI by intents after every few millisec and so on is not really efficient.

What do you think ?

Comment: How about [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service and shedule to run it by [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

TimerTask is all you need please read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)